# How to use text extracted from the "grep" command as an argument in a bash script?

Tags: environment-variables, scripts, grep

I have a file called "krylov_methods", which has text like this:

```
cg     - preconditioned
cgne   - normal equations
nash   - cg subject to constraint
stcg   - another method for constraints
gmres  - general minimum residual
...
```

I need to extract the first word (character string) of each line, one by one, in a shell script and use it as a command line argument within that script.  To extract the first word, I used the following command:

```
head -1 krylov_methods | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
head -2 krylov_methods | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
head -3 krylov_methods | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
...
```

This seems to work well for extracting the first word of each line one by one
However, I need to be able to store the character string as a variable for future use within the script.  For example, since the first word of the first line of the file "krylov_methods" is the word "cg", I want to be able store "cg" to a variable called "method".  Within the script, I would like for it to get something like:

```
method=cg  
./execute $method
```

Is this possible to store the result of the 'head' command used within a shell script?

Comment: To isolate the n-th line of a file is better to use `sed`. For example, to extract the third line: `sed -n '3{p;q;}' filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    set -- $line
    method=$1
    /path/to/execute $method
done
```

You could read the first word into an array as well.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

### Alternative

`read` can isolate each component of the line:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read METHOD MINUS COMMENT
do
    echo "METHOD = $METHOD"
    echo "COMMENT = $COMMENT"
    /path/to/execute $METHOD
done
```

sort of depends on what you are doing with the information and how you want to call it later.

Comment: +1 Good idea to use `read`. And we can improve your answer because `read` can isolate the components of the line => it simplifies the script (and make it more portable ;). I preferred to edit your answer instead of adding another one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after some experimenting, I figured it out:

```
method=$(head -$i krylov_methods | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}')
execute $method
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use both `head` and `tail`. `AWK` can print the line that you tell it to quite easily

```
$> awk -v LINE=5  'NR==LINE' /etc/passwd                                                                              
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
```

You can turn that into a function in your `bash` script (remember to quote the full or partial path to file if it has spaces or special chars):

```
print_line_number() {
    awk -v LINE="$1" "NR==LINE" "$2" 
}
```

And here it is in action

```
$> print_line_number 5 /etc/passwd                                                                                    
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
```